# Oracle Procedure to detect long running SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I need to create an SQL Procedure that can detect any long running SQLs from non DBMS users that run longer than a certain time period. I got all the relevant Information with a Select Statement:

```
    select s.username, s.machine, db.name, s.last_call_et, sq.sql_fulltext, s.sql_id, s.status, s.serial#
    from v_$session s, v_$sql sq, dba_users d, v$database db
    where s.sql_id = sq.sql_id
    and s.username = d.username
    and s.status  = 'ACTIVE'
    and s.last_call_et > 50
    and d.default_tablespace <> 'SYSAUX'
    and d.default_tablespace <> 'SYSTEM';
```

My Question now is, how do i insert the data from the SELECT statement  into two tables (dba_long_sqlstat, dba_hist_long_sqlstat) and if a long running SQL was detectet more then once in the same houre there should only be one record in the DBA_HIST_LONG_SQLSTAT. In the DBA_LONG_SQLSTAT table it doesnt matter how many records of the same SQL there are, just that the records should not be kept longer then 24h.

is this possible somehow?

Comment: Please join the 21st century and use explicit joins. It will help you avoid missing join clauses, like how nothing is linking `db`, so it will cross join...

Comment: This is my first SQL Procedure that im doing, so thank you for the Tipp :) the db.name isnt linked, because it fits to every record. It will just show the Instance name wich is important for the Alerting Mail

Comment: you could create a view that combines your two tables and then change up your SELECT to do a INSERT as SELECT...as for only having the single record, you could use a MERGE statement to just update the time or add a unique or check constraint to the table